# wxPython: Retina images

Tags: wxpython, retina-display

I am trying to create an application using wxpython for mac. Currently I am trying to optimize it for retina displays but have not found a way to add a @2x image.

Is there a branch which can use @2x images? Specifically its a tray icon application. The tray icon is basically loaded with the following code calls:

```
icon =  wx.Image(os.path.join(imagePath(),'normalMacIcon.png'),wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
wxIcon = wx.IconFromBitmap(icon.ConvertToBitmap())
self.SetIcon(wxIcon)
```

Update 1:

I actually found a way to display retina images normally. As of 2.9.5 the code is included:

```
png = wx.EmptyBitmap( 1, 1 )
png.LoadFile(os.path.join(imagePath(),'PresenceOnlineMono.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

The LoadFile function has the needed additions. See this log: http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/src/osx/core/bitmap.cpp?r1=74303&r2=74511

Sadly to be able to set the Icon I have to call
    wx.IconFromBitmap(png)

And the tray icon does not reflect retina quality although it does use the retina file.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the tray icon code and it was not possible to create retina tray icons. I have since sent a patch which should fix this. http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15887